# To store multiple values of form using AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I need to store two values from a screen using AsyncStorage and also store it in the format of key value pairs.I want this data to be stored locally in the mobile and later retrieved from it when needed.
I have tried to retrieve single data but haven't been able to do with multiple data.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, TextInput, View, Alert, Button, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class FormData extends Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
    // myKey: '',
      key: '',
      text1: '',
      text2: '',
      getValue: '',
      infoValue:''
   };
 }
 savefunction = () => {

   let storedObject = {};
       storedObject.textval1 = text1;
       storedObject.textval2 = text2;
       try {
           AsyncStorage.setItem('allTextValue', JSON.stringify(storedObject));
       } catch (error) {
       }
 }
 getfunction = () => {
   try {
               AsyncStorage.getItem('allTextValue').then((infoValue) => {
               let resObject = JSON.parse(infoValue);
              let textval1 = resObject.text1
              let textval2 = resObject.text2
             }).done();
            } catch (error) {
            }
 }
render (){
   return(
     <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Text style= {styles.TextComponentStyle}>User Form</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Email"
          onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ text1: value})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Password"
           onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ text2: value})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <Button    onPress={this.savefunction}
              title="Save key" color="#2196F3" />

        <Button  onPress={this.getfunction}
                    title="Get key" color="#2196F3" />
        <Text style={styles.text}> {this.state.getValue} </Text>
</View>
    );
  }
}

export default FormData;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10,
},

TextInputStyleClass: {

textAlign: 'center',
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
// Set border Hex Color Code Here.
 borderColor: '#2196F3',

 // Set border Radius.
 borderRadius: 5 ,

},
text: {
  fontSize: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
},

 TextComponentStyle: {
   fontSize: 20,
  color: "#000",
  textAlign: 'center',
  marginBottom: 15
 }
});
```

I expect multiple data to be stored in the map with key value pair

Comment: The code about saving it is fine, it saves an object with the 2 values inside the asyncStorage. When you retrieve it and do the JSON.parse it returns the desired object with both the values. What's the problem?

Comment: i am not able to get the desired result.moreover i want it like key value pair

Comment: What do you mean? How do you want to access that value? resObject.textval1 would return the string you want. Now that i'm looking it look like you are doing resObject.text1 that would be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saving the price properly. You declare a status value and are putting a value into a variable with the same name. Code needs to be modified.

```js
 savefunction = () => {

   let storedObject = {};
       storedObject.textval1 = this.state.text1;
       storedObject.textval2 = this.state.text2;
       try {
           AsyncStorage.setItem('allTextValue', JSON.stringify(storedObject));
       } catch (error) {
       }
 }
...
 getfunction = async () => {
   try {
             const infoValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('allTextValue')
               let resObject = JSON.parse(infoValue);
              let textval1 = resObject.textval1
              let textval2 = resObject.textval2
              console.log(textval1);
              console.log(textval2);
            } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only part i see a problem is where you get the values from the object when you get the items:

```
let resObject = JSON.parse(infoValue);
let textval1 = resObject.textval1
let textval2 = resObject.textval1
```

You can also change it to

```
let resObject = JSON.parse(infoValue);
let {textval1, textval2} = resObject
```

Comment: ok i will change it and how do i see the get item data somewhere to ensure that i saved the correct data

Comment: Do console.log(resObject) and check for it after the parse, you should be able to see the whole object

Comment: im not able to use getitem properly

Comment: getfunction = () => {
   try {
               AsyncStorage.getItem('allTextValue').then((infoValue) => {
                 let resObject = JSON.parse(infoValue);
                 let {textval1, textval2} = resObject;
              console.log("text1 and text2 is" + resObject );
             }).done();
            } catch (error) {
            }
 }  iam not getting the stored value.the value im getting is {object,object}